# die( ) function isn't getting executed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP and I'm confused why the same thing that was working in a YouTube tutorial isn't working with me. So here's the code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$conn = 
mysqli_connect($servername, 
$username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . 
mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

When I'm giving the right values for $servername ,$username and $password, it's working fine, but when I'm giving the wrong values,it should execute the die()and statement inside should show up on the screen but instead a fatal error is showing up there.

I'm using the latest version of xampp. What can I do to fix this?

This is showing up:

`Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpflammy\index.php:7 Stack trace: #`

Comment: Try `echo mysqli_connect_error(); die;`

Comment: I've tried that too.Still it's showing the same things.

Comment: "*instead a fatal error is showing up there*" Why haven't you provided the full text of the error here in the body of your question as prescribed by [ask]?

Comment: It might be throwing an exception instead. It depends on the default exception mode (IMHO, the default should be to throw exceptions).

Comment: In that case, put a `try { ... } catch($e) { die($e); }` if you want to see the exception.

Comment: I copied the exact code and it worked for me. what does `var_dump($conn);` give ?

Comment: ```var_dump($conn)``` is returning an ```object(mysqli)```

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation says:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

> If mysqli **exception mode** is not enabled and a connection fails, then
> mysqli_connect() returns false instead of an object.

And
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php says

> Depending on the flags, it sets mysqli error reporting mode to
> **exception**, warning or none

Thus you have an exception instead of returning a false value.
You should use "try...catch" statement instead of if() or change mysqli error reporting mode. See an example in the second link:

```
    
    try {
        /* if the connection fails, a mysqli_sql_exception will be thrown */
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

        // Do other things...

    } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
        error_log($e->__toString());
    }
```

Note:

> As of PHP 8.1.0, the default setting is MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR |
> MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT. Previously, it was MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF.

Comment: Finally it helped me.Thanks man:)